# Issue with checksum : Upgrading from MySQL version 5.1 to 5.6

Tags: mysql

I am in the process of upgrading MySQL from version 5.1.48 to 5.6.17. I took a dump and loaded the data successfully to the latest version. But when I compared the checksum of all the tables, there is quite a mismatch for some tables. Per my understanding storage for DATETIME, TIME and TIMESTAMP increased from version 5.6 , and hence the checksum mismatch for tables with these data types is understandable . But there is a checksum mismatch for some other tables as well? I looked at the number of rows and the data and every thing looks fine. Does the difference in checksum over different mysql versions here means there was some issue with the data porting ?

Any help in understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem, after googling , I found percona tools 1.x is suitable for this.

http://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/percona-toolkit/12555-is-pt-table-checksum-with-replication-rewrite-db-enabled-on-the-slave-working?p=12579#post12579